# Variadic methods in C++ and recursion

Tags: c++, methods, variadic

I've been studying variadic classes and methods in C++ and am trying to figure out the recursion. In short, is it necessary to always create three methods for variadic methods that need to recurse? As I understand, it's necessary to handle when the parameter pack is unpacked, whether there's none, one, or more values inside it. Is this correct, or is there something additional in variadic methods that I'm missing?

```
void printf(std::string& in) {}

template <typename T>
void printf(std::string& in, T val) {// code}

template <typename THead, typename... TsTail>
void printf(std::string& in, THead valHead, TsTail... valTail) {// code}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make do with just two overloads:

```
void printf(std::string& in) {}

template <typename THead, typename... TsTail>
void printf(std::string& in, THead valHead, TsTail... valTail) {// code}
```

The second overload above will be selected if there's just one argument other than the `std::string`.  I.e. the compiler will more than happily deduce a parameter pack to be empty, and you can deal with an empty parameter pack (e.g. applying `std::forward` to all arguments therein) as though it weren't empty.

Comment: Interesting, but what do you mean "you can deal with an empty parameter pack (e.g. applying std::forward to all arguments therein)"?

Comment: Say you have an empty parameter pack introduced by `typename... Args` which gives the types of arguments `Args &&... args`.  You can validly call another function, and supply as arguments `std::forward<Args>(args)...`.  This will compile and will supply zero arguments to the function being called.

Comment: I thought there's no way to deduce if the parameter pack is empty? So, if you're calling `printf` recursively should you pass the `valTail` pack as `std::forward<TsTail>(valTail)...`?

Comment: @user3791372: What are you talking about?  Also: In your example code, if you plan on using `std::forward` you should take your arguments as `TsTail &&... valTail`.  You can also examine the number of arguments in a parameter pack with [`sizeof...`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...).

Comment: I'm not sure, I must be confused! Some experimentation is required I think! Thanks!